# Mock lambda test tool throwing error in .NET project in VS 2019/2022

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to debug my AWS Lambda function written in c# (AWS template lambda function, issue remains for any type of Lambda function) and when I'm doing the mock lambda test it's throwing this error:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
> The program '[23460] dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1.exe' has exited with code 2147516570 (0x8000809a).

I tried upgrading the version but didn't work. Tried installing the lambda test tool but got an error saying:

> Package 'Lambda test tool 3.1' has a package type 'dotnetTool' which is not supported by your project.

Then I tried basic rebuild and clean solution but got the same error.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure and double check the target framework and runtime of the lambda and the one that you have it there.
2. Go to `C:\Users\YourName\.dotnet\tools` and delete `dotnet-lambda-test-tool`.
3. Delete the lambda and clone it again.
4. Open the lambda and execute it if an error pops up about the `dotnet-lambda-test-tool` is not in your folder `C:\Users\YourName\.dotnet\tools`, ignore it and run it again, because it will download that automatically in your folder;

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Instead of deleting the code and re-cloning, I just went to the folder and did  a 
git clean -xdf and that worked for me.  I was getting a stop on a Startup.cs file that did not exist.